# How to fix unintended background overflow

Tags: html, css

My question is about unintended overflow. I made a web page yet the body overflows all other elements. I have set the width to 50% 100% 150% and no matter what i do, 1/4 of the body overflows. I tried adjusting div elements width and still could not fix the problem

https://codepen.io/pnkonx/pen/LgPwKE

```
 body{
   background-color:#f7ce58;
   color: #5e1c10;
   font-family: stylish, sans-serif;
   height: 100%;
   width: ;
```

here is a link to the project i am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h1` is the guilty one.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 60%;
  width: 65%;
}
```

Remove the margin value and use `text-align: right` instead.

---

For the next times, use this short snippet to fix it quickly.

```
* {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was in the middle of re-building the page from scratch to try and identify the problem, yet it seems so obvious now. I appreciate your time and feedback, this fixed my problem.